# Automatic updating project from a Gitlab repository after a push to a Production server

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, production

I have a Gitlab server with all my projects.

I have a Production server running my applications.

The 2 servers are in the same network.

When I do modification to an application and push it to my Gitlab server, how then to automaticaly deploy this new application version to the Production server ?

I first used a cron on the Production server, running every minutes and pull the project from the gitlab server with a "git pull" command for that project. It works but : it's useless to run a cron every minutes if I push to my project one time a month !

I saw that there are gitlab-ci or hooks to do that but I dont really understand how and where use it.

Maybe have a post-receive hook on the Gitlab server ? But how do a "pull" to my Production server from the Gitlab server ?   Do I need to "just" clone the project from Gitlab server to Production server ? But cloning send ALL files from the project and not only the only file I changed : copying a whole project instead of a single file is not very usefull !

Thanx for your advice

Comment: How do you deploy your aplication manually? `I need to "just" clone the project` That strongly depends on the "application" and what do you mean by "deploy".

Comment: I connect to the Production server with ssh and do a git pull in the project repository but I don't want to do that because some users don't have account on the Production server (Linux). They just commit/push to the Gitlab server and the deployment to the Production must be automaticaly updated after the push. The process must remain transparent and simple for those users.

Comment: `connect to the Production server with ssh and do a git pull in the project repository` Great - so do _exactly the same_ from  gitlab-ci script. Connect to your production server from gitlab-ci script and pull the project repository.

Comment: Where do I store the  gitlab-ci script ? Server side (Gitlab) or Client side (Production) ?

Comment: You store it server side. But https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ci_cd_for_external_repos/ and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#trigger and also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#specify-a-custom-cicd-configuration-file allows it store anywhere else. And https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/protected_environments.html#protecting-environments alows to hide your ssh key. But maybe doing a separate project with git submodule and doing `trigger:` from your project `gitab-ci` would be a great separation and would hide everything from the developers.

Comment: Thanx I will try but I dont know how to handle ssh part, wich credential to use to ssh connect to the Production server for users NOT having account on the Production server. There are multiple user having their own projects/application on the Gitlab Server and they will wrote their own gitlab-ci script to update the Production server

Comment: Another way is just setuping gitlab-runner with shell executor on the production server, and just `rsync`ing it locally after cloning. `how to handle ssh part, ` Just literally search "how to handle ssh in gitlab ci" in google, it's all there. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239768/discussion-between-fabrice-and-kamilcuk).

Comment: @KamilCuk hummmm I read few time that I must "install GitLab Runner on the infrastructure you own or control but just make sure that it is installed on a different machine from the one that hosts an instance of GitLab." I don't understand this part : so where install GitLab Runner ??? I just have my Gitlab Server and my Production Server !!!

Comment: If you _want_ to install gitlab-runner at all, that depends on how you want to solve it - I would go with connecting from gitlab-ci with ssh. The gitlab-runner shell executor is confusing for me. `so where install GitLab Runner?` On the production server.

Comment: I don't WANT to install gitlab-runner, but it seems mandatory to use gitlab-ci...or I missed something...

Comment: Yes, you have to have to a gitlab-runner instance somewhere to run gitlab-ci. You can install it on the same workstation as the server, or even on your personal PC.